# What does the eligibility to review again time depend on?

Tags: discussion

After reviewing 40 posts, there comes a message thanking you and saying you should come in X hours to continue reviewing:

[image]

That eligibility time is different every time: 2, 12, 16 and even 23 hours.

What does that X it depend on?

Comment: Waiting for a New UTC day.

Comment: [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899/289905).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limits for each queue are per day, with each day based on UTC time. The “countdown” is relative to midnight in UTC time (i.e., 00:00:00+00:00).